# Unable to find "Destroy" link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to write test scenario for delete,but i don't understand why it is not getting destroy link.

Here my test scenario:

```
 Scenario: User can delete kids
   Given I am on the kids page 
   When I Destroy kid
   Then I should see "Kid deleted successfully"
   Then one kid should not exist



<h1>Listing kids</h1>

<tr>
 <th>Kid name</th>
 <th colspan=3>Action</th>
 </tr>
<% @kids.each do |kid| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= kid.kid_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', kid %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kid_path(kid) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', kid, method: :delete,
                        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
 </tr>
```

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Kid', new_kid_path %>

My step defination for link:

`When /^I Destroy kid$/ do |link|`

```
   click_link(link)

 end
```

Please somebody suggest step definition for delete link, please correct me if their is some error in my scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the step that is looking for the link?

Comment: Can you post the content of ./features/step_definitions/event_steps.rb:32:in `/^I follow "([^\"]*)"$/'

Comment: @techvineet this is the content When /^I follow "([^\"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
 end

Comment: Are you sure there are any kids to destroy?

Comment: @JustinKo yes there are kids to destroy.My concern is that why it is not getting the destroy link even though destroy is present in index.html.erb.Would you please suggest the step definition for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for destroy link. It won't support webrat so i have removed webrat and used capybara and my issue get solved.

Here is the step:

`Scenario: Delete Kid`

Given I am on the kids page

And there is a kid with kid_name "john"

When I destroy that kid

Then I am on the kids page

step_defination:

`When /^I destroy that (.*)$/ do |element_type|`

```
   element = element_type.classify.constantize.last

   path = "#{element_type}_path"

   case page.driver

when Capybara::RackTest::Driver

   page.driver.submit :delete, send(path, element), {}

else 

  visit send(path, element, { method: :delete })
```

end

```
end </code>
```